# Why does the HG4930 IMU have better specifications than the HG1700, even though it's almost certainly worse?

Tags: imu, gps

I was browsing and looking at different IMUs and came upon the following Honeywell page:

https://aerospace.honeywell.com/us/en/learn/products/sensors/inertial-measurement-units

There they have a table comparing a bunch of IMUs. I was looking at their RLG-based HG1700 and their MEMS-based HG4930. I am fairly certain that there is no way that the HG4930 is a better sensor than the HG1700, yet it beats or equals the HG1700 in all areas except for the turn-on bias specifications, which to my understanding aren't the most important if you have access to a GNSS aid for some amount of time. It's even lighter, smaller, and uses less power.

HG4930:

In-run gyro bias: 0.25deg/hr
In-run accel bias: 0.025mg
Turn-on gyro bias: 7deg/hr
Turn-on accel bias: 1.7mg
ARW: $0.04^\circ/\sqrt{hr}$

HG1700:

In-run gyro bias: 0.25deg/hr
In-run accel bias: 0.05mg
Turn-on gyro bias: 1deg/hr
Turn-on accel bias: 1mg
ARW: $0.125^\circ/\sqrt{hr}$

I don't really believe that the HG4930 is a better sensor than the HG1700 for, say, estimating position and attitude. So, what's the catch?

Comment: `I don't really believe that the HG4930 is a better sensor` - It would really help us address your concerns if you could articulate **why** you think it's not a better sensor. You say you are `fairly certain that there is no way that the HG4930 is a better sensor than the HG1700` without justification.

Comment: Well for one it's hard to get a straight and clear idea because manufacturers routinely try to paint their products in the best light they can. I wouldn't be surprised if the in-run bias for the HG4930 was recorded under ideal (and unrealistic) conditions, because that level of bias (in my research) is unusually low given the size and weight of that sensor. In my experience RLG/FOG tactical-grade IMUs are almost universally better performing than their MEMS counterparts.

Comment: I mean, the table on the webpage I linked appears to be listing the IMUs, from left to right, _by performance_. It doesn't _say_ that, but the specifications would seem to imply that with the sole exception of the HG4930

Comment: Also I would be willing to bet 100,000:1 odds that the HG1700 is significantly more expensive due to the RLGs, which wouldn't really make sense to me if the IMU is overall a worse sensor (higher or equal levels of nosie) than the 4930

Comment: Somehow missed that you're comparing a ring laser gyro to a MEMS gyro. You're comparing consumer-grade (4930) to a tactical-grade (1700) device. Not really about the measurement performance here so much as the +/- 70 g range, I think. 

You're looking at the ranking left-to-right as *performance*, when I think the ranking is by *cost*. Usually that's the same thing, but the performance driving cost there isn't the measurement performance.

Comment: Ah ok, gotcha, thanks Chuck. Would you classify the HG4930 as a tactical grade device, though? It's performance, especially it's bias instability (also called in-run bias I believe) is 0.25deg/hr. Everything I can find bases the performance grade on that spec, and 0.25deg/hr is pretty low for that IMUs size and weight, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm a mechanical engineer that got into realtime simulation software - I don't do anything with drones, missiles, and haven't done physical hardware stuff in a long time. Would I personally call it tactical? Nope, I think I'm with you in that I would want my guided missiles or whatever to have super accurate pose estimates, but I also don't know what other criteria they're using to qualify it as "tactical." I was honestly surprised to see the poorer performance and same temperature band, but there could be other things that they're looking at to call it "tactical."

Comment: Off-gassing, MIL-STD connectors, altitude/vacuum range, Ingress Protection (IP) ratings, country of origin, startup time, housing material, etc... there's a lot of things to consider that aren't covered in the datasheets I'm finding online, but yeah generally I agree with you 100% - looks like the 4930 is the better IMU in my opinion. I've dealt with Honeywell application engineers in the past and they've been super responsive - you could just reach out to Honeywell and ask what features differentiate the two.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah I will ask. Interestingly I was researching the leading tactical IMUs on the market (namely this page: https://www.unmannedsystemstechnology.com/feature/selecting-an-inertial-measurement-unit-imu-for-uav-applications/)  and they never mentioned any honeywell IMUs. It seems like the 4930 has every right to be called "tactical" given its performance specifications but is rarely referred to as such.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are important but there are many other metrics to evaluate sensors on. No sensor is best in all applications. You've already called out size, weight, and power consumption. There are other characteristics such as reliability, physical robustness, max acceleration and rates measurable before saturation, sensing quality in the presence of noise factors. Many of these properties are implied in the datasheet by the differentiation of the technologies inside MEMs vs RLG. I'd suggest that you read up more on the different technologies.

MEMs devices are newer and are improving more. [Here's an article asking if they are better already](https://semiengineering.com/are-todays-mems-gyros-good-enough/) but it still comes down to what your application requires rather than a generic statement of "better" and what do you value most in the various cost benefit tradeoffs.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there are a lot of specs I don't understand that aren't as simple. I'm just looking for ability to track vehicle attitude and position in the absence of aiding factors (I realize all but the best IMUs will diverge very rapidly). Essentially, the longer the IMU can be used in hold-over mode, the better I consider the sensor.